# How to see how many leads particular user qualified?

Tags: dashboard, analytics, custom-reports, activity

I am preparing a dashboard for my client. It is a side thing, I do mostly ads for them but I said I could try to help with salesforce. Basically, my client wants to know how many leads each of our users qualified.

Is it possible to track such a metric?

Side question: Can I add such lead qualification event so it counts as Activity?

Thanks,
Erw

Comment: Have you tried creating a report using Leads as a report type?

Comment: Hi, yes I created a report using Leads as a report type, but I can't see the column such as let's say "Qualified by".

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce, there are many tutorials available at Salesforce [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/).

Comment: You'll likely need to work with your client to determine how lead qualification is reflected in their data model.